# Error Installing APK

Tags: android, performance, android-studio

Getting error while installing APK via android studio

`pkg:/data/local/tmp/com.securetech.mobilinkbiometricmodule
Failure [INSTALL_PARSE_FAILED_MANIFEST_MALFORMED]`

`$ adb shell pm uninstall com.securetech.mobilinkbiometricmodule
Unknown failure (Failure)
Error while Installing APK`

Comment: For this issue you need to do possible things.
1.Remove apk from device.
2.If already removed then re-start device.
3.Also restart IDE(android studio) and run application.

Comment: Add your manifest file code

Answer (score 2):

There are some android standards in coding structure that we should always follow. This issue have different reasons like:

Your app package name should be always in small letters.

In manifest your activity should be define either with package name or it should have '.' At start of it's name.

Comment: getting error because activity is not started with (.) dot in manifest